# How to save data into a DB from a Modal popup in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I have a plain view which is saving data correctly into a DB, however when I put that view into a Modal popup into another page it is not saving any data into the DB, the Modal is just displaying. What else need to be done in order to save the data into a DB from the popup? Thanks

This is the Controller:

```
public function actionEditMyPopup()
{
    $model = new MyPopupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->insertEditMyPopup();
        return $this->renderAjax('edit-mypopup', ['model' => $model]);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('edit-mypopup', ['model' => $model]);
    }   
}
```

This is the View of the popup:

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'edit-mypopup-form', 'options' => ['data-pjax' => true],]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'attribute1') ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'edit-mypopup-button']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

And the Model has the variables declaration and the function insertEditMyPopup() that insert data into the DB.

```
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
class EditMyPopupForm extends Model
{
    public $attribute1;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
              [['attribute1'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

    public function insertEditMyPopup()
    {
        //attributes is the name of the table
        $a = new attributes();
        $a->att1 = $this->attribute1;
        $a->save();

    }//end function  
}//end class
```

Comment: share the code in : `insertEditMyPopup()`

Comment: A simple $model->save() would suffice. unless your're doing additional processing in `insertEditMyPopup()`

Comment: I have tried with $model->save() after the function insertEditMyPopup() on the Controller and it did not work. The function on the Model just insert data into a DB. What could be wrong? Because the MVC flow works correctly without the Modal popup.

Comment: please post what you have in `insertEditPopup()`

Comment: please share what you have on `insertEditPopup()`

Comment: I have added the Model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome the issue by adding the following code on the js file:

```
$('body').on("click", "form#edit-mypopup-form", function() {
    var form = $(this);
    if (form.find('.has-error').length) {
      return false;
    }
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(results){

                 $(form).find('.results').html(results); 

            }
        });
         return false;
});
```